# Resize image in C# without losing quality

Tags: c#

```
static Image ScaleImage(Image image, int Width, int Height)
{
        int originalWidth = image.Width;
        int originalHeight = image.Height;

        double ratioX = (double)Width / (double)originalWidth;
        double ratioY = (double)Height / (double)originalHeight;
        double ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);

        int newHeight = (int)(originalHeight * ratio);
        int newWidth = (int)(originalWidth * ratio);

        Image scaledImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
        Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(scaledImage);

        graphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        graphic.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        graphic.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        graphic.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

        graphic.Clear(Color.Transparent);
        graphic.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);

        return scaledImage;
}

        Image full = new Bitmap("img.png");
        Image scaledImage = ScaleImage(full, full.Width / 2, full.Height / 2);
        Clipboard.SetImage(scaledImage);
```

The problem is that, after resizing using this code, the image is kind of blurred.

I want to copy to clipboard a version of original image, but scaled(2/3 times smaller) and if I past the image somewhere and manually resize this(to a bigger resolution), I want the same quality as original one.

How can I do this?

Comment: It mathematically isn't possible. When you reduce the resolution by 2/3, you throw away information. The quality when you resize back up depends on the upsize algorithm, not as much the downsize algorithm. It's like saying I want to eat 1/3 of a pie, then spread the pie out to make the original pie again - you can't.

Comment: Ok, I thought so, but I noticed that it is possible to manually downsize an image (lets say in MS Word for example), and then resize to original size and it will be like original.
Also, why after resizing the image is blurred?

Comment: @DoubleNy Because you threw pixel information away.  Word isn't resizing the base image, just how it shows up.  That's why it "resizes" without information loss.  The original pixel information is still there.

Comment: It is possible to downsize an image without losing quality?

Comment: use Graphics Transform.

Comment: That depends on what you mean by quality. In Word (and PowerPoint), you don't resample the image (change the number of pixels). When you rescale the image, it just causes Word to draw the same pixels in a different amount of space, which might involve throwing pixels away for presentation depending on output device resolution, or it might be adding pixels because you are printing to a high resolution color printer. The original image is unchanged. That's why there is a Compress Pictures option in Word under Picture Tools - that actually throws away the pixels to make the document smaller.

Answer (score 0):

try this one code, it's almost like yours, but i use it in my own pictures viewer and dont see any "blur".

It dont resize each side, it put picture in square with MaxImageSizeToResize side and save proportions. May be you see blur because of not proportional resize, or lost some properties.

Try it and say - is result the same or not.

```
public static System.Drawing.Bitmap Resize(string pathToOriginalFile, int MaxImageSizeToResize)
    {
        using (var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(pathToOriginalFile))
        {
            return LocalGet(image);
        }

        System.Drawing.Bitmap LocalGet(System.Drawing.Image image)
        {
            int rW = 0;
            int rH = 0;

            double c = 0;
            c = ((double)image.Height / (double)MaxImageSizeToResize);
            rW = (int)(image.Width / c);
            rH = MaxImageSizeToResize;

            var destRect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, rW, rH);
            var destImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(rW, rH);

            destImage.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

            using (var graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(destImage))
            {
                graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
                graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

                using (var wrapMode = new System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageAttributes())
                {
                    wrapMode.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);
                    graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel, wrapMode);
                }
            }

            return destImage;
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Maybe you should try images with text.